# How to use darknet in my own project?

Tags: c, deep-learning, darknet

I have installed [Darknet](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/) and I can run it from the command line for various tasks, for example:

```
./darknet classifier train cfg/cifar.data cfg/cifar_small.cfg
```

This will train a classifier CIFAR data using the network architecture specified in `cfg/cifar_small.cfg`.

OK, but how to use Darknet in my own C project? For example, I would like to call `load_network()`, `train_network()`, `save_weights()`, and `network_predict()` declared in `darknet.h` from within my own code.

Can I use Darknet as a static or a shared library for this? I don't see any instructions on how to do this on the website.

So far the only method I have is creating my own source file in the style of the examples in the examples folder, and modifying `darknet.h`, `darknet.c` and `Makefile` to give myself an entrypoint I can call from the commandline similar to the classifier example I posted above. But this doesn't feel ideal because I'd like to have my own project structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it appears that the Makefile supports generating both a shared and a static library, and these are made by default when running the installation:

```
git clone https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet.git
cd darknet
make
```

Afterwards `libdarknet.a` and `libdarknet.so` appeared in my darknet directiory.

So I could `#include darknet.h` in my own project, and then compile via:

```
gcc -Wall -o myprog main.c -ldarknet
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who are interesting in details and who use CMakeLists.txt, here are highlights, assuming Darkned already compiled:

```
# Path to Darknet project folder.
set(DARKNET_PATH /home/<custom_path_to>/darknet)

# Give a custom name to shared library which is provided by Darkned when 
# the one compiled.
set(DARKNET_LIB_NAME libdarknet)

# Link Darknet library' include folder.
include_directories(${DARKNET_PATH}/include)

# Define Darknet library' shared library.
add_library(${DARKNET_LIB_NAME} SHARED IMPORTED)

# Set a path to Darknet library' shared library
set_property(
        TARGET ${DARKNET_LIB_NAME}
        PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION 
        "${DARKNET_PATH}/libdarknet.so"
)

# Link all libraries together.
target_link_libraries(${PROJ_NAME} ${DARKNET_LIB_NAME})
```

The project that use Darknet library is provided on next link:

[DarknetApp](https://bitbucket.org/ChernyshovYuriy/darknetapp/src/master/)